# 2d array and for loops

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I did this code to try the basic operations on bidimensional arrays (2d arrays), but it doesn't print
on screen the letter 'A'.
Can someone help me figure this out?
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS  2
#define COLS  3

int main()
{
    int x; 
    int y; 
    int i; 
    int j;
    int Field[ROWS][COLS];

    printf("Enter two values: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    Field[y][x] = 1;

    for(i = ROWS - 1; i > 0; i--){
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
            if(Field[i][j] == 1){
            printf("A");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: `i > 0` should be `i >= 0`. Also what is the input?

Comment: This code has a large number of issues.  Can you describe a little bit more about what you are trying to do so we can help?

Comment: what is input? you are giving to this program

Comment: @hanie - `scanf` is used to get input.

Comment: @ryyker I know , I think it's possible that besides  `i>0` that should be `i>=0` ,the problem of not printing `"A"` comes from giving input out of boundaries of array.

Comment: @hanie - you are correct.  This has been addressed, but you could  consider adding your own answer if you believe your insight would help :)

Answer (score 1):

This: `for(i = ROWS - 1; i > 0; i--){` fails to traverse the necessary array location, and does not clearly convey to future maintainers of your software what exactly the intent is.

However, to do what you have described in your problem description, unless there is a compelling reason to set up a decrementing index (`--`), a normal incrementing (`++`) set of for loops is adequate and more idiomatic :)

```
for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        if(Field[i][j] == 1)
        {
            printf("A");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the outer loop

```
for(i = ROWS - 1; i > 0; i--){
```

the range of indices is (in the descending order) [ROWS-1, 1], So the index 0 is not processed in this loop.

It is better such a loop to write the following way

```
for ( i = ROWS; i != 0; i-- ){
    for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
        if(Field[i-1][j] == 1){
        printf("A");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the variable `i` can have even an unsigned integer type as for example `size_t` and the code will be valid even when `ROWS` is equal to `0`.
Otherwise the expression `ROWS - 1` can yield the maximum value of the unsigned type when ROWS is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned `i>0` should be `i>=0` other wise you won't traverse the array completely.

also note that even after you you corrected that statement , it's better to check input `x` and `y` , because if they are greater or equal to `ROWS` and `COLS` , than by passing boundaries of your array here `Field[y][x] = 1;` your program will lead to undefined behavior.

so I suggest this

```
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    if (x < ROWS && y < COLS)
    Field[y][x] = 1;
    else
    return 0;
//rest of your code with i>=0 in this loop for(i = ROWS - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code adds some protections to out of bounds arrays and prints 'A'.  Should be a good starting point for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS  2
#define COLS  3
int main()
{
    int x,y,i,j = 0;
    int Field[ROWS][COLS]; // 2 Rows 3 Column array

    printf("\nEnter row value less than %i: ",ROWS); 
    scanf("%d", &y);

    printf("\nEnter column value less than %i: ",COLS); 
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if(x >= COLS || y>= ROWS)
    {
        printf("\nOut of bounds inputs!");
        return 0;
    }

    Field[y][x] = 1;

    for(i = ROWS - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if(Field[i][j] == 1)
            {
                printf("A");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I would also correct your loops as other users have mentioned.  Both other answers have big improvements in that category.